# Regexp and variable

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have this form, wich outputs some letters and a wordlength. But I've got some problems with getting a right output from my database.

```
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $letters = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['letters']);
        $length = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['length']);
        echo "Letters: $letters";
        echo "Lengte: $length";
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT word FROM words WHERE word REGEXP '[$letters]{$length}' ")
         or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            echo $row['word'];
            echo "<br />";
        }
     }
     else {
         echo "Foutje";
     }
```

If I change $length to the integer that was inputted by the form my script works. Copy/pasting [$letters] 6 times works also. I guess there is a problem with quotes but I totaly can't figure out what it exactly is.

Can anyone see what I did wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Ensure that the input won't break the regexp pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{}` are being interpreted by PHP as delimiters for the variable inside since you are using a double-quoted string. Change your quoting around with concatenation:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT word FROM words WHERE word REGEXP '[" . $letters . "]{" . $length ."}'")
```

Or double up the `{}` inside a double-quoted string so the outer pair are interpreted as literals.

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT word FROM words WHERE word REGEXP '[$letters]{{$length}}' ")
```

Note, you should also verify that `$length` contains a positive integer.

```
if (!ctype_digit($length)) {
  // error - length must be an int
}
```

Comment: The last one did it. Thanks, I've totaly forgotten that option!

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
res=mysql_query("SELECT word FROM words WHERE word REGEXP '[".$letters."]{".$length."}' ")
```

I have a hunch that the $ is getting intepreted as part of the regex